# Session is passed, but $_SESSION is not

Tags: php, html, session

I am trying to pass a graph object from jpgraph from one page to another. To pass the object to the next page, I save it as `$_SESSION['graph']`.

To pass the session to the next page, I add it to the URL with

```
echo '<a href="...../next.php?SSID='.session_id().'">Next</a>';
```

In next.php, I get the SID and start the session:

```
session_id($_GET['SSID']);
session_start();
```

But when I try to access `$_SESSION['graph']`, I get the error *Undefined index: graph* and subsequently, it crashed when I try to call the `Stroke()` function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure you are calling session_start on the page where you assign the graph

Comment: Why are you taking the session to the next page? The session will continue automatically.

Comment: Are you sure that `SSID` is properly set?

Comment: yes, the session is started correctly, I check the `session_id()` output on both pages, they were identical

Comment: Do **NOT** put session IDs into urls. Consider what happens if a user shares that link to someone else. Now that someone else can hijack the original user's session.

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour is that the session id will be stored in cookies and not in GET vars. This is controlled by the following php.ini values:

```
session.use_cookies=1
session.use_only_cookies=1
```

Which both default to `1`.

So unless you have changed this, you won't need that GET var as the session id is stored in a cookie that will be passed along with request - automatically.

Just do this:

```
session_start(); // will get session id from cookie and resume the session
$graph = $_SESSION['graph'];
```

Comment: @AndMim do you starting the session in the document that generates the link?

Comment: cannot say much to this. only: if you make all things right, then the code in my answer will do the trick